# how to populate async call from inside another

Tags: javascript

I have a script that makes multiple API calls, and the result of one call effects the others.

```
async function getPlugin(id){
  const fetchCardPlugin = `https://*********..amazonaws.com/*****/cardPlugin?id=${id}`
  const cp = await fetch(fetchCardPlugin)
  let pluginData = await cp.text();
  pluginData = JSON.parse(pluginData);
  if (typeof pluginData[0] != undefined){
    return pluginData[0]['value'].split(':').pop().split('')[0]
  }
  else {
    return ''
  }
}

elm.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    return t.get('board','shared','bid')
        .then(data=>{
            (async function(){
        const sheetId = data;
        const cardList = [];
        const mm = {};

        const fetchCardData = `https://*******.execute-api.******.amazonaws.com/******/cardData?id=${boardId}`
     
        const cd = await fetch(fetchCardData)
        let cardData = await cd.text();
 
        cardData = JSON.parse(cardData);
              
        await cardData.map(x=>{
          const cardDict = {};
          // console.log(getPlugin(x.shortLink));
          cardDict['points'] = getPlugin(x.shortLink);
          cardDict['id'] = x.id;
          cardDict['title'] = x.name;
          
        })
```

My first call goes to my `fetchCardData`.  I then use the data from this return to both create an object, and make another call.

```
await cardData.map(x=>{
          const cardDict = {};
          // console.log(getPlugin(x.shortLink));
cardDict['points'] = getPlugin(x.shortLink);
          cardDict['id'] = x.id;
```

My big sticking point is that, I need to use data from the second call to populate the object.  Currently when I do this I am getting a `Promise` for the objects point value.

```
comments:0
description:""
id:"6354b75ddared4ba013aa06440"
labels:""
last activity:"Sat Oct 22 2022"
list:"To Do"
members:""
points:Promise
[[Prototype]]:Promise
[[PromiseState]]:"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]:"5"
title:"test"
url:"https://trello.com/c/*******/**"
```

What I would like is this:

```
comments:0
description:""
id:"6354b75ddared4ba013aa06440"
labels:""
last activity:"Sat Oct 22 2022"
list:"To Do"
members:""
points:5
title:"test"
url:"https://trello.com/c/*******/**"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const cardListPromises = cardData.map(async (x) => {
  const cardDict = {};
  cardDict['points'] = await getPlugin(x.shortLink);
  cardDict['id'] = x.id;
  cardDict['title'] = x.name;
  
  return cardDict;
})

const cardList = await Promise.all(cardListPromises);

console.log(cardList) // this is the final result you need.
```